# x is a variable storing some html coming from AJAX call. how can i extract the attributes of that HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How do I find the attributes of an HTML that is coming from ajax call?

```
var x = table_row.find('td:nth-child(5)').html();  
var y = x.getAttribute("id");  // im doing this but this is not working
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get x object id you can do it like
`var y = x.prop('id')`

Comment: it is showing type error : x.prop() is not a function

Comment: y = table_row.find('td:nth-child(5)').prop('id') should solve type error